# checking nested arrays for a winning combination w/JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm a web development student working on a Tic Tac Toe game.

Assuming the squares on the board are numbered 1-9, I have an array of three-element arrays representing winning combinations. I need a way to check each player's squares owned for those combinations. I think I'm going to need nested `for` loops but I can't get it to work. I've tried searching `owned` for `winners` and searching `winners` for `owned`.

Any thoughts? I'm using jQuery but would be happy with a vanilla JavaScript solution too.

EDITED: To be clear, in Tic Tac Toe the order of `winners` and the order of player moves is meaningless. At the end of a typical game `xOwned` could be [9, 4, 7, 3, 8] and that should result in "X wins!" because it has [7, 8, 9] in it.

```
  var xOwned = [];
  var oOwned = [];
  var winners = [
    ["1", "2", "3"],
    ["4", "5", "6"],
    ["7", "8", "9"],
    ["1", "4", "7"],
    ["2", "5", "8"],
    ["3", "6", "9"],
    ["1", "5", "9"],
    ["7", "8", "9"]
  ];

//when a player clicks on a square the value/number 
//of that square (i.e., 1-9) is pushed into their array.

var game = {
  score: function(){
    for (var i = 0; i <= xOwned.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if($.inArray(xOwned[i], winners[j]) !== -1) {
          victory.html("X wins!");
        }
      }
    }
    for (var k = 0; k <= oOwned.length; k++) {
      for (var l = 0; l < 3; l++) {
        if($.inArray(oOwned[k], winners[l]) !== -1) {
          victory.html("O wins!");
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: what is the content of `xOwned` and `oOwned`?

Comment: We have no way to know what the interface does do populate the arrays

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include the whole program - when a player clicks on a square the value/number of that square (i.e., 1-9) is pushed into their array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you need to ensure that either xOwned or oOwned contains one of the sequences in *winners* array and winning sequence is always 3 elements. This could be done like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<winners.length; i++) {
   // It's only 3 elements do you really need to loop?
   if (xOwned.indexOf(winners[i][0]) > -1
        && xOwned.indexOf(winners[i][1]) > -1
        && xOwned.indexOf(winners[i][2]) > -1) {
       // x won!
       break;
   } else if (oOwned.indexOf(winners[i][0]) > -1
        && oOwned.indexOf(winners[i][1]) > -1
        && oOwned.indexOf(winners[i][2]) > -1) {
       // o won!
       break;
   }
}
```

Or less code but less clear:

```
for(var i=0; i<winners.length; i++) {
   if (!winners[i].some(function(n) { return xOwned.indexOf(n) < 0; })) {
       // x won!
       break;
   } else if (!winners[i].some(function(n) { return oOwned.indexOf(n) < 0; })) {
       // o won!
       break;
   }
}
```

Reference [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Ok I'll try to explain condition in second piece of code: if no elements of winning sequence is not in players' "moves" sequence means that all elements in winning sequence are in players' "moves" sequence and therefore that player won.

Comment: Edited original post to be clearer about the role of sequences.

Comment: My answer is not dependent on order

Comment: Totally rad. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You may use a function which checks every winning position:

```js
function win(array) {
    return [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],
        [3, 6, 9],
        [1, 5, 9],
        [3, 5, 7] // <-- please change this line to this value!
    ].some(function (a) {
        return a.every(function (b) {
            return ~array.indexOf(b);
        });
    });
}

document.write(win([1, 4, 7]) + '<br>');
document.write(win([1, 4, 8]) + '<br>');
document.write(win([9, 4, 7, 3, 8]) + '<br>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `var xOwned = [];` holds three results such as:

```
var xOwned = ["1","2","3"],
    oOwned = ["2","2"];


score: function() {
  var _x = xOwned.sort(),
    _o = oOwned.sort(),
    xWin = false,
    oWin = false;

  winners.forEach(function(i) {
    var _i = i.sort();
    for(var l = 0; l < i.length-1; l++) {
      xWin = _x[l] === _i[l];
      oWin = _o[l] === _i[l];
    }  
  })
  if(oWin) victory.html("O wins!");
  if(xWin) victory.html("X wins!");
}
```

[See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mygo4ouh/)

Comment: players' moves accrue in strange orders and they might not get a winning combo until the very last square on the board is played.

Comment: I edited my answer, if you do not need to account for the player answer's order

Comment: I'm hazy on where the argument `i` is coming from. Should I pass in `winners` there (i.e., the array of arrays)?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach Basically, `i` represent each item of your `winner` array. So on the first iteration, i will be `["1","2","3"]`. On the second, il will be `["4", "5", "6"]` and so on. It is just like writing `for(var j = 0; j < winners.lenght; j++) { var i = winners[j] }`

Comment: I ran this and it set xWin to true at the right point in the loop but then it reset it to false on the next pass. When it was done with the loop it remained false.